# Ios Jailbreak-How does this happen?

Tags: ios, kernel, payload, userland

i am wondering how hackers create jailbreak.I know what means Userland exploit and kernel exploit.I know that when I have userland exploit I need to find kernel exploit.But I really don't know what means "payload", "ROP","ROP Payload","payload".How this interconnect with userland and kernel exploits???
Can somebody do "scheme" for this?
Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is the place for specific questions regarding programming and tools that assist programmers. This is not the place to ask about how to go about jailbreaking iDevices or getting someone to explain to you about how that works.

Answer (score 0):

ROP is a form of programming it is used because well no other method will work as of iOS 4.3. The payload is what you use when exploiting so you find a say kernel exploit in vm_map_copyin() like mdowd that you can use in an app, your payload is essentially the code that patches and runs your code.